# Testing UWP app using random events

Tags: testing, win-universal-app, windows-10, windows-10-universal, random-testing

For test Android application we can use the command line tool [Monkey](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkey.html). A long time ago, we used [Hopper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5253) to check the app stability on Windows Mobile.

And now for Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps? Is there any tool to generate ramdom events to test application? I'm not talking about achieve that by using  [Coded UI Test Builder](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=pt-br&tl=en&u=http://talkitbr.com/2016/01/29/criando-testes-automaticos-para-aplicacoes-universal-windows/).